# cgminer installation

Tags: 13.10, radeon, bitcoin

I just installed 13.10 on my Satellite C855-12Z(which has AMD Radeon HD 7610M), I will use this laptop primarily for bitcoin mining with ASICs, because it uses less power than a regular PC.

But here I run into a bit of a problem, when I tried to install **cgminer** apt wanted to uninstall AMD graphic drivers and installed nVidia ones.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing bfgminer, is more easy to configure with asic:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:unit3/bfgminer
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt-get install bfgminer
```

How to use:

```
  bfgminer -o http://eu.triplemining.com:8344 -u dansanti_linux -p dansanti
```

[here are more](http://probandoubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/05/bitcoin-moneda-virtual-transacciones-y.html) info how to build cgminer, in case you want to use it anyway

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question - how to use cgminer:

Obviously the only solution is to file a bug report to the developers and hope that it is going to be fixed.

(I ran into the same problem here on a notebook with ATI Radeon 7550M/7570M/7650M mobile graphics.)